# Paging error with EntityDataSource

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I'm using an EntityDataSource and creating a projection using the CommandText property to query across several tables. I want to allow paging, but when I run the code I get an error that says

> For the EntityDataSource, if the query specifies a projection and
>   paging is enabled, a sort expression must be defined. Either set the
>   OrderBy property or set AutoGenerateOrderByClause to true

Odd thing is, I HAVE set the AutoGenerateOrderByClause to true and the error persists. I'm not sure what to do at this point. Here's my example EntityDataSource code.

```
<asp:EntityDataSource runat="server" ID="EntityDataSource"
    ConnectionString="name=AssetRegistryEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="AssetRegistryEntities"
    CommandText="SELECT a.astName, a.astDescription, r.rolFK_adCN 
                 FROM AssetRegistryEntities.Assets as a
                 JOIN AssetRegistryEntities.Roles as r ON r.rolFK_astID = a.astID
                 WHERE r.rolFK_adCN = 'dpellerin'
                 AND r.rolTypeCode = 'PRIANALYST'"
     AutoGenerateOrderByClause="true">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Anyone know how to make paging work with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a projection. Either get rid of the SELECT or also add OrderBy="it.astID"

Comment: That did the trick! Not sure I fully understand why though. Have to do some more reading. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the accepted answer of AFD.

Change the EntityDataSource to the following:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource runat="server" ID="EntityDataSource"
    ConnectionString="name=AssetRegistryEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="AssetRegistryEntities"
    OrderBy="it.astID"
    CommandText="SELECT a.astName, a.astDescription, r.rolFK_adCN 
                 FROM AssetRegistryEntities.Assets as a
                 JOIN AssetRegistryEntities.Roles as r ON r.rolFK_astID = a.astID
                 WHERE r.rolFK_adCN = 'dpellerin'
                 AND r.rolTypeCode = 'PRIANALYST'"
     AutoGenerateOrderByClause="true">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```